# MySQL - How to get total number of matches within a column

Tags: mysql

I tried this code:

```
SELECT SUM(bookingstatus)
FROM beo_eventorder AS TotalBookingStatu
WHERE bookingstatus = 'Tentative';
```

But this returns 0. There are 6 matches in the table.
Why does this not return 6?

Screenshot of column:

[image: Screenshot of column:]

Comment: in mysql, is `bookingstatus` an `int` or a string?

Comment: @timgavin string sir

Comment: @Harsh Got it sir. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `count` instead of `sum`:

```
SELECT count(bookingstatus) FROM beo_eventorder AS TotalBookingStatus WHERE bookingstatus = 'Tentative';
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` adds all the elements on the column, in your case, it added all the strings to be 0. You should use a `COUNT` function instead.